# R: How to fix namespace error?

Tags: r, namespaces

I want to use the `NGramTokenizer` from `RWeka` but for some reason I get this error:
I need the following function

```
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
bigramWords.dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(SentenceVector)), control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
```

So I installed RWeka:

```
package ‘RWekajars’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘RWeka’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

But:

```
> library(RWeka)
Error : package ‘methods’ does not have a namespace
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’
```

I also get namespace errors installing packages like:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/SomeUser/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘methods’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘assertthat’, ‘BH’
```

Comment: Did you update all of your packages and restart R? Seems like it might just be a quirk.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for the fast help. Yes. I restarted several times  also I used `rm(list = ls())`. Packages are also up to date. I user RStudio is this a problem? EDITstart I tried even in R directly - use Windows editEND

Comment: Do you have Java installed on your machine?

Comment: @Thomas The actual version of Java Runtime is installed. However (but I think this shouldn't matter) it is not active for the browser.

Comment: @Thomas Do you know an possible `workaround`. I added the function (need to make bigrams) above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Thomas This is not really a solution. However, it helped. Since you told me it could be related to Java. I tried the code on my laptop.. It worked :) Thank You! Nice! ... Do you think this is worth to write it as a solution? I'm new here so I don't want to offer pseudo-solutions, but it helped.

Comment: Yea, I can't offer more help because I don't have Java on the machine I'm currently on, but received a similar (albeit somewhat different) error trying to load the package. If you can track down the difference between the two situations, you should *definitely* post it as an answer. Answering one's own questions is encouraged, when it will help others in a similar situation.